# Compare 2 Tab Delimited files and output differences with Column Header and No Primary Key in File

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to compare 2 Tab Delimited files and output differences with Column Header and No Primary Key in File.

I am very near to it but what I am facing the problem is the Snippet i have reached into is working if and only if it has a Primary Key-

```
awk '
NR==1 { 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    header[i] = $i
}
NR==FNR {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    A[i,NR] = $i
  }
  next
}
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if (A[i,FNR] != $i)
      print "ID#-" $1 ": " header[i] "- " ARGV[1] " value= ", A[i,FNR]" / " ARGV[2] " value= "$i
}' t1.csv t2.csv
```

Can anyone please help me how to achive it

1. When I don't have any primary key in it
2. When Number of Rows are not same and one file has missing records

t1.csv

```
Month   ClientSegment   ClientType  IssuerClientSegment NetworkID   VD
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   0   OTHER   
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   OTHER   
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   5   OTHER
```

t2.csv

```
Month   ClientSegment   ClientType  IssuerClientSegment NetworkID   VD  
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   0   OTHER
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   OTHER1
2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   PUSH
2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   3   OTHER
```

Expecting Output Like:

```
Row 2, Column: VD- t1.csv value=  OTHER / t2.csv value= OTHER1

Missing in t2.csv
Month   Client Segment  Client Type Issuer Client Segment   Network ID  VD
2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   5   OTHER

Missing in t1.csv
Month   Client Segment  Client Type Issuer Client Segment   Network ID  VD 
2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   PUSH
2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   3   OTHER
```

Comment: edited for better understanding

Comment: cuurent logic i am not able to incorporate Missing Items, also it is only working when i am having a Valid Key Column at the First Column

Comment: What do you mean by OTHER / OTHER1 ?! Can you please give us all information needed how to compare?

Comment: If you See Row 2 , the Column named VD has Different Value OTHER in one FIle and OTHER1 in another file, so basically it should point out the Row , and Column name and the Values in files where it is differing

Comment: But why is OTHER vs. OTHER1 not  in the Missing section while OTHER vs. PUSH is?

Comment: @pLumo - Good Question , my bad , the first 5 columns should be always unique, will correct it

Comment: @αғsнιη - corrected the sample input and output , please have a look now, my bad made a mistake earlier, the first 5 columns are always expected to be unique

Answer (score 1):

Use [`daff`](https://github.com/paulfitz/daff):

```
daff --input-format tsv t1.csv t2.csv
@@  Month   ClientSegment   ClientType  IssuerClientSegment NetworkID   VD
    2020-12 COMMUNITY       EXEMPT      COMMUNITY           0           OTHER
→   2020-12 COMMUNITY       EXEMPT      COMMUNITY           2           OTHER→OTHER1
+++ 2020-13 COMMUNITY       EXEMPT      COMMUNITY           2           PUSH
+++ 2020-13 COMMUNITY       EXEMPT      COMMUNITY           3           OTHER
--- 2020-12 COMMUNITY       EXEMPT      COMMUNITY           5           OTHER
```

Install using `pip install daff` (you migh also need `sudo apt install python-pip`).

Comment: can u plzz help me to have this achieved in more programmatic way rather than a package?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
{ key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 }
! secondInput {
        file1[key] = $6
        NRfile1[key] = NR
        next
}
(key in file1) {
        if (file1[key] != $NF) { print "diff-line#:", NRfile1[key] "|" FNR, $0 }
        delete file1[key]
        next
}
{ print "missing in file1: ", $0 }
END {
        for (key in file1) {
                print "missing in file2: ", key, file1[key]
        }
}' file1 secondInput=1 file2
```

Outputs:

```
diff-line#: 3|3 2020-12 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   OTHER1
missing in file1:  2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   2   PUSH
missing in file1:  2020-13 COMMUNITY   EXEMPT  COMMUNITY   3   OTHER
missing in file2:  2020-12 COMMUNITY EXEMPT COMMUNITY 5 OTHER
```